# Find the top 5 values in Excel and highlight the cells

Tags: excel

I would like to select the top 5 values for each row, highlighted them and also put those values on AH as illustrated on the attached worksheet. Because the data is updated constantly I need the formula updates as data is changed.
Any help is appreciate. [New image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ji3E.jpg)

I changed the original picture with a smaller one. I hope this one will be better.

I want put on U4 the numbers 7, 5, 2, 16, 18 which are the reference numbers (C3:T18) for the top5 values of the row 4. Of course formula will go down to the rest of rows.

Thank you.

Comment: Please take a few moments and tidy up your question by including the relevant data directly in this post.  It is difficult to read your screen capture.

Comment: Sry, I just have to ask - do you want a BigMenu with that, sir?

Comment: This is two questions: one how to conditionally format the cells to highlight the top five, and the second how to get the top five in one cell.  Please choose one at a time.  Put a smaller batch of data that describes the problem as text in the Original Question using [edit].  Also explain what you have tried to accomplish this goal.

Answer (score 1):

for the output:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,LARGE(A1:K1,ROW($1:$5)))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter

for formatting:

```
=RANK(A1,1:1)<6
```

Just adjust the ranges so they meet your requirements ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the Top 5 column put the formula

```
=LARGE([range],1)&","&LARGE([range],2)&","&LARGE([range],3)&","&LARGE([range],4)&","&LARGE([range],5)
```

where `[range]` is the row of data.

To conditionally format, create the below rules to each highlight the cells that

```
= cell >= LARGE([range],5)
```

Comment: Conditional format rule: `=A1>=Large($A1:$Z1,5)` where A1 is the upper left of the range wanting to be formatted and the data is in Columns A through z.

Comment: I changed the original picture with a smaller one. I hope this one can be better.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1:
Use Conditional Formatting with Rank

```
=RANK(A2,$A2:$AD2)<=5
```

Part 2:

```
=CONCATENATE(LARGE(A2:K2,1),",",LARGE(A2:K2,2),",",LARGE(A2:K2,3),",",LARGE(A2:K2,4),",",LARGE(A2:K2,5))
```

Comment: Dirk Reichel >> I wont be able to get results.  <br/>
Abe Gold & Matt >> I can get the top 5 large values but I'm unable to highlight the cells as I run the formula to get the top 5. Because the data change a highlighted cell may need to change as another get high value. <br/> 
Tim Biegeleisen & Scott Craner >> I understand and sorry about that. How can I put a excel file on the post? I was unable to do that.  <br/>
Thank you to all of you for your time.

Comment: You need to use conditional formatting on the entire range.

Comment: ooh... I got it. Thank you. I'm very glad for everyone help.